# Среда программирования

Tags: windows, ide, c++

Посоветуйте среду программировани для *Windows 7* начальная , кроме *visual studo*.

Для *С++*.

Comment: Самая лучшая IDE для программирования на С++ - линукс (на крайний случай мак). Там все есть и почти все "из коробки".

Answer (score 4):

Довольно большой список IDE для C/C++ есть [в википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_IDE)

Я пользуюсь [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Помимо студии, только если QtCreator или Eclipse.

Comment: еще забыл упомянуть NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

Советую попробовать [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads)